# OAuthをローカルでテストする方法

Tags: oauth

OAuthを使ったプロジェクトがほぼ完成したので本番環境にデプロイしたのですが、そこでcallback URLがlocalhostのままだと本番環境ではなくローカルに飛んでしまうことに気づきました。
本番環境を動かしつつローカルでもOAuthのテストを実行できるようにする方法はないでしょうか？

追記：
言語はpython（Django)、対象サービスは今の所TwitterとTumblrです

Comment: これは(1)開発環境で動作しているプロジェクトを「そのまま」本番環境にデプロイする、(2)プロジェクトのcallback URLには「localhost」が「固定的に」指定されている、状況であっていますか?

Comment: 「固定的に」というかSNSのアプリ登録でcallback URLを指定していて変えられない状態です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API連携開発方法の質問かと思いますのでそのように回答します。

一般的に開発環境やローカル環境などの環境でOAuthなどのAPIのテストする場合は、
開発用専用のサンドボックスやアカウントを作成しておくことが一般的です。

それらを環境ごとに分けて運用します。
分ける方法はいくつかありますが、環境ごとに違うデータで管理します。
一般的に言うと
・環境変数
・設定ファイル
・DB
などでしょう。

また
開発やローカルのアカウントと本番では実際のアカウントを分けることで、
もし開発環境で事故が起こった際にも本番環境には影響なく、安定した稼働も期待できます。

安定稼働や開発運用のしやすさから考えて、アカウントは別で運用するようにしましょう。

Comment: アプリを2つ作ってOAuthキーを別ファイルに保存し、そのファイルをgitの無視リストに入れてローカル環境か本番環境かを判別できるようにして開発するという感じですかね

Comment: そうですね。それが回答にある「・設定ファイル」という方式です。

Answer (score 0):

> callback URLがlocalhostのままだと本番環境ではなくローカルに飛んでしまうことに気づきました。

WEB アプリ から OAuth を行う場合

facebook の場合だと

```
https://www.facebook.com/v7.0/dialog/oauth?
  client_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={"https://www.domain.com/login"}
  &state={"{st=state123abc,ds=123456789}"}
```

のように リダイレクト先の url をパラメータで 指定しているはずです。
お使いの OAuth の部品で この url 生成をどのように行っているのか調べてみてください。

お使いの言語、フレームワーク、ライブラリ等が記載されると より具体的な回答ができると思います。

### 追記に対する追加の解答

Django と Twitter の場合 なら
[DjangoでTwitter認証アプリケーション](https://qiita.com/Kyou13/items/713a878065df82a0ecc3)
に書いてあることがそのまま当てはまるのですかね。

通常 callback URL は クライアント側のURLを ライブラリが自動的に
実行中の WEB サーバーの 情報を利用するはずです。

上記リンク先では リダイレクトURLは

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/user/top' # リダイレクトURL
```

のように 相対パスとして記述しています。
これによって、配布先のサーバーのURLが変わったとしても リダイレクト先のURLは
自動的にその 配布先のサーバーになります。

また Twitter 側で リダイレクト先のURLを チェックするため
リダイレクト先の `URLs` を複数登録することで
複数のサイト(開発用本番用）で1つの OAuth アプリを利用する事ができます。

[Callback URL not approved by Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103139/callback-url-not-approved-by-twitter)